# Non-Muslims will not accept islam unless Muslims worship with non-Muslims?

Tags: quran, non-muslim, reference-request

Could someone please direct me to the chapter and verse of the Holy Quran in which it is said that non-Muslims will not accept Muslims until Muslims worship with non-Muslims?

Answer (score 2):

### The part you request of the verse:

In English:

> And never will the Jews or the Christians approve of you until you follow their religion.

In Arabic (the exact words):

> وَلَن تَرْضَىٰ عَنكَ الْيَهُودُ وَلَا النَّصَارَىٰ حَتَّىٰ تَتَّبِعَ مِلَّتَهُمْ ۗ

### The whole verse:

In English:

> And never will the Jews or the Christians approve of you until you follow their religion. Say, "Indeed, the guidance of Allah is the [only] guidance." If you were to follow their desires after what has come to you of knowledge, you would have against Allah no protector or helper.

In Arabic (the exact words):

> وَلَن تَرْضَىٰ عَنكَ الْيَهُودُ وَلَا النَّصَارَىٰ حَتَّىٰ تَتَّبِعَ مِلَّتَهُمْ ۗ قُلْ إِنَّ هُدَى اللَّهِ هُوَ الْهُدَىٰ ۗ وَلَئِنِ اتَّبَعْتَ أَهْوَاءَهُم بَعْدَ الَّذِي جَاءَكَ مِنَ الْعِلْمِ ۙ مَا لَكَ مِنَ اللَّهِ مِن وَلِيٍّ وَلَا نَصِيرٍ

---

***Surah Al-Baqarah — Chapter / Number of the Surah in Qur'an (2) — Verse (120)***

[A webpage source](https://quran.com/2/120)